# How to pad strings using preprocessor macros

Tags: c, string, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to pad a string with spaces (or any character) using only preprocessor macros? If so, how?

Example:

```
#define SOME_STR               "v1.1"
#define STR_PAD(str, len)      // <-- padding defined string

#define SOME_STR_PADDED        STR_PAD(SOME_STR, 10)        // evaluates to "v1.1      "
```

I know that there are simple solutions during runtime, but my question is how  to pad a string during *compile time*.

Comment: Than may be reword you question so that you are asking the real question? Quote from you: `...my question is if it is possible to pad...` and my answer is - Yes, it is possible.

Comment: I asked if it is possible (a) and if it is possible, how to do it (b). English is not my native language, but I thought that it's getting across. I'll reword the question that everyone will understand. Thank you.

Comment: Very interesting question! It does not seem possible in the general case where both `str` and `len` are unknown, and also when `str` alone is unknown. If both the length of `str` is known and `len` is bounded by some reasonable fixed value, one could generate a compound ternary expression that compiles to a single string constant.

Comment: Though it's already been answered as such, I want to make a distinction to make something clear.  The preprocessor cannot determine the length of a string constant, so it cannot do what is asked.  But there's a lot more that goes on during *compilation*; asking if the preprocessor can pad versus can you pad at compile time are two different questions (with different answers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very interesting question! It does not seem possible in the general case where both `str` and `len` are unknown, and also when `str` alone is unknown. If both the length of `str` is known and `len` is bounded by some reasonable fixed value, one could generate a compound ternary expression that compiles to a single string constant.

Here is an illustration:

```
// compile time padding: str must be a string constant and len <= 4 + strlen(str)
#define STR_PAD(str, len)  (((len) + 1 <= sizeof str) ? str :        \
                            ((len) == sizeof str) ? str " " :        \
                            ((len) == sizeof str + 1) ? str "  " :   \
                            ((len) == sizeof str + 2) ? str "   " :  \
                            str "    ")
```

Comment: I think, you mean "len is < 4 + sizeof str" in your comment

Comment: @Ctx: good catch. There was also an off by one error due to `sizeof(str) == strlen(str) + 1`

Comment: That's a good idea! I didn't think of the ternary expression.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, the preprocessor can convert tokens to strings, but it cannot modify existing strings at all.  What it *can* do is place string literals next to each other (`"foo" "bar"`), which is translated at compile time -- albeit not formally by the preprocessor -- equivalently to the concatenated string (`"foobar"`).

You could, therefore do something like this:

```
#define VERSION "v1.1"
#define APPEND_10_SPACES(s) s "          "

printf("%s", APPEND_10_SPACES(VERSION));
```

With *considerably* more difficulty, you could arrange to append a number of spaces specified by a macro argument, too.  Your web searches should turn up several results pertaining to making the preprocessor mimic iteration.

What the preprocessor absolutely cannot do, however, is determine or use the length of a string literal, so as to allow you to do something equivalent to padding a literal to a specific length.  If you need that, then you could potentially rely on a workaround along these lines:

```
char padded[] = APPEND_10_SPACES(VERSION);
padded[10] = '\0';
```

You do not that way get your desired string as a literal, but you do get it, at the cost of allocating up to 10 more bytes than you need, and truncating the original string if it was in fact longer than 10 characters.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Of course you are right, at compile time there is more going on than running the preprocessor.

In fact I want to append a varying number of spaces corresponding to @chqrlie's answer. As you mentioned, you could probably write a wrapper so to mimic a loop.